# JS deactive checkbox selection not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm facing a little issue with one of my JS and it would be great if you guys could have a quick look and give me a feedback.
On my site I have a JS which simulates the selection of checkboxes onto an image.
http://cormilu.com.br/loja/monte-seu-kit/monte-seu-fio-de-luz/

When users select a checkbox the string is filled with balls of that color (active). When users deselect the checkbox it should take away the balls again(deactive).

The function colorDeactive is defined as following:

```
function colorDeactive(_item) {
        _item.removeClass('active');
        _item.attr('data-timestamp', '');
        _item.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    }
```

activating and deactivating the balls on the string is handled here:
    // bind
        $('#input_59_13 > li').find('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click',        function(e){ 
            var _this = $(this);

```
        // check if this item is already actived
        if(_this.hasClass('active'))
            colorDeactive(_this);
        else
            colorActive(_this);

        console.log('cor');
        refreshPreview();
    });
```

It used to work just fine but somehow now it doesn't work anymore (without modifying the script).
Thanks for your help!
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at fixing these errors first:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: gform is not defined(anonymous function) @ (index):64
Uncaught ReferenceError: gformCalculateTotalPrice is not defined(anonymous function) @ gravityforms-product-addons.js:5
Uncaught TypeError: r.yith_magnifier is not a function(anonymous function) @ autoptimize_d6e203920c4cf919b2b249da5c9d7391.js:97
Uncaught ReferenceError: gformCalculateTotalPrice is not defined(anonymous function) @ gravityforms-product-addons.js:5
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The r.yith_magnifier error only appeared because I was changing something. ->solved      The gform errors I cant figure out how to fix but the js used to work properly also with the gform errors.

Comment: Mystery solved. The issue was caused because the call wasn't directed at the parent file.